# How to format data frame each columns with relative format?

Tags: r, dataframe, format

Given a data frame:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=runif(10),c=10*runif(10),d=101:110)
```

each columns format I expect:

```
%2s , %3.1f, %4.3f, %4.1f
```

how to apply the `fmt` on relative columns?

Supplement:
 the data frame will be saved as txt file which is the input data of another software. So I need to keep each columns as numeric data except the first column.

Maybe I ignored the format of R. Further explaination: format  `%3.1f` means this cell is 3 character width with 1 decimal digit. It is a numeric ,not character (string). `%2s` mean output 2 width length character, etc..

Comment: No, you can save characters to a text file and import as numbers into the other software. Just set `quote = FALSE` in `write.table`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map` to iterate over two inputs. Then you can assign into the data.frame:

```
df[] <-  Map(sprintf, fmt, df)
```

or use this to create a separate data.frame:

```
"[<-"(df,,value = Map(sprintf, fmt, df))
#    a   b     c     d
#1   1 0.3 2.060 101.0
#2   2 0.4 1.766 102.0
#3   3 0.6 6.870 103.0
#4   4 0.9 3.841 104.0
#5   5 0.2 7.698 105.0
#6   6 0.9 4.977 106.0
#7   7 0.9 7.176 107.0
#8   8 0.7 9.919 108.0
#9   9 0.6 3.800 109.0
#10 10 0.1 7.774 110.0
```

Comment: It output is `charactor` type by using `sprintf`. I want numeric data.

Comment: @Cobin Please clarify what you need then. Do you want to round numbers (just use round with my approach) or do you care about how the numbers are printed (then you could create a class and a `print` method).